# In Django how can i get aggregated data on more than two models

Tags: django, orm, models, aggregate, django-queryset

```
class Book(models.Model):
    # fields

class Chapter(models.Model):
     book = models.ForeignKey(Book)

class Page(models.Model):
     chapter = models.ForeignKey(Chapter)
```

If i want to know the number of pages in that specific book 'A', what is the best way to achieve this?

Of course i can cycle on chapters of Book A and sum the pages of each chapters, but i don't think is the smarter way.

Is there a way to do this through the ORM / Queryset? Some kind of aggregation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this could work:

```
book_a = Book.objects.get(name='A')
page_count = Page.objects.filter(chapter__book=book_a).count()
```

This will result in a database join, which will return the count of pages whose chapter is from book A.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
from django.db.models import Count

page_count = Book.objects.filter(name='A').annotate(Count(chapter__pages))
```

The result should be in `page_count[0].chapter__pages__count`. Check out the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) for more information.